# Rename the [docker-notary] tag to [notary]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

In October 2017, Docker contributed its Notary project to CNCF: https://www.cncf.io/announcement/2017/10/24/cncf-host-two-security-projects-notary-tuf-specification/

So, this is a retag request to rename [docker-notary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-notary) to [notary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notary).

Comment: Done. In addition to the fact that Docker no longer sponsors this project, I'm not a big fan of vendor name prefixes. As long as there's no ambiguity, [notary] is just fine. We don't allow questions about [notarial sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary).